# ¿Cómo colocar datos de variables de PHP a un JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json, json-schema

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es un **schema** de JSON y pasarla información que esta guardada en variables de PHP.

No se si ésta sea una forma correcta de hacer este ejemplo:

```
<!-- Schema JSON -->
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
      "@type": "Product", 
      "name": "<?=$variable_de_php?>",
      "image": "https://bomgos.com/images/logo.png",
      "description": "<?=$variable_de_php?>",
      "brand": "Tienda en Linea"
    }
    </script>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es llenar el name y la description con información que está guardada en una variable de PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba hacerlo de esta manera para que no tengas que abrir y cerrar php

```
<?php
$schema= [
    '@context' => 'https://schema.org/',
    '@type' => 'Product',
    'name' => $name,
    'image' => 'https://bomgos.com/images/logo.png',
    'description' => $descripcion,
    'brand' => 'Tienda en Linea',
];

?>

<!-- Schema JSON -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
    <?php echo json_encode($schema, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: La verdad es que me ha funcionando, pero he notado un problema y es que cuando voy a ver el código fuente de la pagina para ver si todo esta correcto, noto un problema con el **Slash** (/) y tal parece que me lo esta colocando doble y no quiero que esto afecte el SEO de mi pagina por no aparecer las URL de formas correcta. Me esta saliendo las URL de esta manera: `https:\/\/bomgos.com\/images\/logo.png` si  te fijas están apareciendo los **Slash** dobles en las URL

Comment: Tienes razón, me ha faltado añadir el flag `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` al `json_encode`, te lo he corregido.